# Content moves when browser resizes

Tags: html, css, resize, positioning

I'm fairly new at css and html but trying to learn as much as I can. 
I'm working on a simple "splash page" for a site (www.revivalfest.org). I have a background div that resizes with the browser, however my content (the video and social media icons) moves around when resizing the browser. I want the video centered under "Savannah, Ga" and to stay there regardless of browser size and screen resolution.

I've tried placing it in a container as well as fiddling with various div widths and wraps but have had no luck. Hopefully y'all can help with this.

Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Revival Fest Coming Soon</title>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <style type="text/css">
   html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}

        #background {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;}

          .stretch { min-width:100%; min-height:100%; width:auto; height:auto; }

        #video {position:absolute; z-index:0; top:310; left:482;}

        #fb {position:absolute; z-index:0; top:755; left:175;}

        #twitter {position:absolute; z-index:0; top:758; left:255;}

   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="background">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.org/revivalfestsav"><img src="http://www.revivalfest.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/revivalsplashmoreinfo67.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="video">
        <iframe width="725" height="432" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kKqHnc91tzk?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="fb">
        <object><a href="http://www.facebook.org/revivalfestsav"><img src="http://www.revivalfest.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/fb.png"></a></object>
  </div>
  <div id="twitter">
        <object> <a href="https://twitter.com/savrevivalfest"><img src="http://www.revivalfest.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/twit.png"></a></object>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Using absolute positioning for layout like that is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Like I said, I'm quite new at this. Could you elaborate? Is there a different approach you would use?

Comment: I would suggest creating your actual text on your site through html rather than just having it embedded in the background. This isn't a great a approach as it doesn't allow the other elements, like your video, to be positioned relatively to the text.

Comment: You could also look into using a grid by the way.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is work with margins in percentages and use media queries to define break points. If you really need the background to be an image like that anyways, otherwise the best thing would be to use physical text so everything can be positioned relatively.